# Solving equation in three variables

Tags: polynomials

please help me understand how the following equation with 3 variables and power of 2 is solved and what solution approach is the quickest.

$$3y^2 - 3 = 0$$
$$4x - 3z^2 = 0$$
$$-6xz+ 6z = 0 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{cases}
3y^2-3=0\\
4x-3z^2=0\\
6z-6xz=0
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
3y^2-3=0\\
x=\frac{3z^2}{4}\\
6z(1-x)=0
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
3y^2-3=0\\
x=\frac{3z^2}{4}\\
6z\left(1-\frac{3z^2}{4}\right)=0
\end{cases}
$$

So, when you solve:

$$6z\left(1-\frac{3z^2}{4}\right)=0$$

We get three solutions for $z$, $z=0$ or $z=\pm\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: is it that simple ? I then plug the three z values into x to get three x-s ? y is +/-1 ? where do I get my third y ?

Comment: @HGOHGO I see no relation between y and the other two varibables

Comment: So, for now $y=\pm1$ and $x=0$ or $x=1$

Comment: should'nt x be 0 or 4/3. The above is the gradient of a function in three variables : the function is 

$$f(xyz)= 2x^2-3xz^2+y^3+3z^2-3y+3$$

Answer (score 1):

**A quick solution**:

By simplification, rewrite

$$\begin{cases}y^2=1\\(1-x)z=0\\3z^2=4x.\end{cases}$$

Then mentally,

$$y=\pm1,\\x=z=0\lor x=1,z=\pm\frac2{\sqrt3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$3y^2-3=0.............(1)$

$4x-3z^2=0...........(2)$

$6z-6xz=0...........(3)$

First, solving the equation(1),

$3y^2-3=0\;\;\;\implies y^2=1\;\;\;\implies y=\pm1$

Now, solving the equation(3),

$6z-6xz=0\;\;\;\implies 6z(1-x)=0$

$z=0,\;1-x=0$

$z=0,\;x=1$

Solving the equation(2),

$4x-3z^2=0$

Put the value of $x$ in equation(2)

$4(1)-3z^2=0\;\;\implies-3z^2=-4\;\;\implies z=\sqrt{\dfrac{4}{3}}\;\implies z=\pm \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$

Thus, $x=1,\;y=\pm1,\;z=0\;or\;z=\pm \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$